# Setting the prototype of a function without __proto__ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I want to create a constructor that has an object as its prototype.

For example:

```
var constructor=function(){
  this.foo=bar;
}

var constructorProto={
  method:function(){}
}

constructor.__proto__=constructorProto;

constructor.method();
new constructor;
```

Functional demo: http://jsfiddle.net/juwt5o97/

This allows me to pass the constructor along and modify it before calling `new`. However, I don't want to use `__proto__` or `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. Is there a "proper" way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think `Object.setPrototypeOf()` is not "proper"?

Comment: prototypes are not static methods, so it's confusing what you want... you can just say `constructor.method=constructorProto.method;`, or use Extend or Object.create() to copy.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that it shouldn't be used, maybe I got it mixed up with `__proto__`. Regardless, it's ES6 and I'd prefer if there's a method that works with ES5.

Comment: *"I remember reading somewhere that it shouldn't be used..."* I think you probably missed the point. They're likely not saying that that particular way of changing the prototype shouldn't be used. They're likely saying you shouldn't change it at all.

Comment: @dandavis The constructor may be created multiple times, so I don't want to recreate the methods for each constructor.

Comment: @LyeFish If there's something similar to Object.create() for functions, then I don't have to change the prototype.

Comment: you can create an object of methods and assign it to the prototype of a constructor. that way, no matter how many times the constuctor is created, or another constructor is created and mounted, the prototype methods stay pre-defined in their stand-alone object.

Comment: @Linksku: If you're saying you want to create callable objects (like subclassing a function), then no, there's not really any way to do it.

Comment: @dandavis that's exactly what I'm doing...

@LyeFish More like being able to call `new` on an object, but it's the same idea.

Comment: @Linksku: you're doing something closely related, but slightly different, what i'm suggesting is to discard `__proto__` and just use `constructor.prototype=constructorProto;` you can always just call `constructorProto.method()` from anywhere if needed, possible with call/apply.

Comment: @dandavis: He seems to want to call methods directly on the constructor object, not on the instances. Not sure why though. @Linksku: why not just add `.method()` to the object directly? You don't need to recreate it. You can use the same one over and over unless it's relying on a unique closure.

Comment: `function method(){}` ...`ctor1.method = method` ... `ctor2.method = method` ...etc.

Comment: right, i'm just saying he can use `constructorProto.method` instead of `constructor.method`, and since he won't be missing _this_, both can work interchangeably with the `__proto__`-style code shown.  ;)

Comment: @dandavis: I'm assuming he wants `this` to be the function, but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: I should probably clarify a bit. I'm trying to make a library (for fun) that simulates classes. `$class()` returns a constructor. I want the constructor to have a prototype containing methods so I can do stuff like `$class().extend(object)`. The `extend()` method is in the prototype. `extend()` modifies the constructor and returns it. Then, I can call `new $class().extend(object)` to instantiate the object.

Comment: Copying the methods from the prototype into the constructor works, I guess that's the best I can do without `__proto__` or `Object.setPrototypeOf()`.

Comment: Well, again it's not anything against those to ways of changing the prototype of an object that's at issue with some. It's the ability to do it at all. They say there are serious performance issues, though I'm not sure if that's true or if it'll change. But yeah, putting a reference on each function returned to a shared method is probably best. It's a very lightweight operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend the prototype of your first class (so that instances inherit the methods) you can do so with `Object.create`:

```
var ClassA=function(){
  this.foo='bar';
}

var protoObject = {
  method:function(){alert('t');}
}

ClassA.prototype = Object.create(protoObject);

new ClassA().method();
```

If you want to just attach static functions to the first function, then you can do it like this:

```
for (var property in protoObject) {
  if (typeof protoObject[property] == 'function') {
    ClassA[property] = protoObject[property];
  }
}

ClassA.method();
```

Comment: This *is* allowing him "to modify it before calling new". He just can't *invoke* it before calling new. That would... not involve the prototype at all. It would just be a static property...

Comment: but i think he want to run `constructor.method()` before an instance is created... it's not a clear question.

Comment: Eh, I'll update my example then, but if that's what he wants... he's misunderstanding how the prototype works

Comment: i'm pretty sure that's the case, but i like how you handle both potentials.

Comment: Thanks. :) And thanks for pointing out that I may have misunderstood what he was looking for.

Comment: @brianvaughn Dandavis is right, thanks for the second case. Is each function still defined only once? I'm guessing `ClassA[property] = protoObject[property]` passes by reference?

Comment: They're passed by reference. You can verify this with `ClassA.method === protoObject.method`